# Angular 2 / TypeScript: How to access observable property in component

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have an observable that gets populated like this:

```
this._mySubscription = this._myService.getSomething(id)
                                .subscribe(
                                    response => this._myData = response, 
                                    error => this.displayError(<any>error),
                                    () => this.stopLoading()
                                );
```

I can access properties for it in my HTML markup using the Elvis operator like this:

```
{{_myData?.PropertyNameHere}}
```

But how do I access the same property in the component using TypeScript?

This produces a squiggly red line under the property:

```
this._myData.PropertyNameHere
```

And says:

> Property does not exist on Observable

**Update**:
Example of service call

```
getSomething(id: string): Observable<any> {

let params = 'id=' + id;

return this._http
            .post(apiUrl + 'SomeController/SomeAction', params, {withCredentials: true, headers: this.headers})
            .timeoutWith(maxTimeHttpCalls, Observable.defer(() => Observable.throw(this._feedbackService.timeout())))
            .map((response: Response) => response.json().data.Items);

}
```

Comment: Can you show the `getSomething` method?

Comment: Sure! I have updated the question.

Comment: I wonder if it's not picking up the Observable you throw in the time out first, so then is interpreting the return type as an Observable.  Can you give it  try without the `timeoutWith` just have it map the response?

Comment: I'm not sure if I see where you type `this._myData`. You may have it set up as an Observable, like `private _myData:Observable;` when it should be either `any`, or some interface type that matches the Items property from the server response.

Comment: Yes, it was declared like this `private _myData: Observable<any>;`. After changing that to just `any` it works. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 3):

`_myData` in the class should not be of type `Observable`. It should be the type of the object that you are returning from the `map` operator in you service.

```
.map((response: Response) => response.json().data.Items)
```

Whatever type `data.Items` is, that should be the type of `_myData`. If you don't know what the type is, then just make it `any`. Then you can do whatever with it without compiler warnings. But if you know the structure of the data, it's best to create a model class for it so you get strong typing

```
interface SomeModel {
  somProperty: string;
}

getSomething(id: string): Observable<SomeModel> {

  return this._http
             ...
             .map((response: Response) => <SomeModel>)response.json().data.Items);
}
```

Your component

```
class MyComponent {
  private _myData: SomeModel;

  this._mySubscription = this._myService.getSomething(id)
    .subscribe((response: SomeModel) => this._myData = response, 
               error => this.displayError(<any>error),
               () => this.stopLoading());
}
```